# How does JosephSilber/bouncer migration work?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

```
Schema::create(Models::table('abilities'), function (Blueprint $table) {
     $table->increments('id');
     $table->string('name');
     $table->integer('entity_id')->unsigned()->nullable();
     $table->string('entity_type')->nullable();
     $table->timestamps();
     $table->unique(['name', 'entity_id', 'entity_type']);
});
```

How does this Models::table() is working? What is the pourpose of this?

Comment: This is very vague. Can you clarify what aspect of it is unclear? The whole thing? A part of it? How the migration works? etc. etc.

Comment: Why they use Models::table('abilities') instead of string "abilities" as the first param of Schema::create? @Pekka웃

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bouncer lets you [customize its tables names](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/blob/8cba56ca8de8a4f090116969d84edf3d41b5f0a4/readme.md#tables):

```php
Bouncer::tables([
    'abilities' => 'my_abilities',
    'permissions' => 'granted_abilities',
]);
```

When you do that, Bouncer will store the custom table names [in its `Models` class](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/blob/8cba56ca8de8a4f090116969d84edf3d41b5f0a4/src/Database/Models.php#L35-L40).

Whenever Bouncer needs a table name, it resolves it [from the `Models` class](https://github.com/JosephSilber/bouncer/blob/8cba56ca8de8a4f090116969d84edf3d41b5f0a4/src/Database/Models.php#L112-L118) with `Models::table($defaultTableName)`, so that it always uses the custom table name.